# Using python's NLTK library to grab dates and the sentences they belong to.

Tags: python, nltk, nlp

I've searched through methods in the NLTK library for methods that grab dates, but I don't know which would be the best for grabbing dates and the sentences they belong to. I know that I should be parsing for DATE name entities, but what method should I use?

I simply need the date and the sentence it belongs to.

Comment: Are the dates guaranteed to be in any particular format? A simple regular expression may be all you need.

Comment: Do you only want 100% confirmed dates in the sentences? Or are you OK with having some items returned which might not be dates?

Comment: Since posting this question I have found the punkt sentence sentence tokenizer to be incredibly useful for isolating sentences. I've then used a simple find method to find number strings that begin with '18', '19' or '20'.

Comment: What would be the best method for searching through a text to find a certain string('19'), then returning the sentence the string belongs to('The Dust Bowl happened in 1934')?

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question I have found the punkt sentence sentence tokenizer to be incredibly useful for isolating sentences. I've then used a simple find method to find number strings that begin with '18', '19' or '20'.

Thanks all for your comments.